# Special characters in HTML even though i have the correct HTML doctype and content type

Tags: html

Hey guys i have this simple HTML page **[HERE](http://codeandcode.co/demo/covebayhotel/conference.htm)**.

I have a HTML 5 doctype and also i have the following content-type declared:

```
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='Type=text/html; charset=utf-8'>
```

So i my content i have the following content:

```
<p><strong>Capacities</strong><br />
                    Boardroom set up - 20 delegates<br />
Classroom style – 15 delegates<br />
U shape – 12 delegates<br />
Separate breakout area available for group work<br />
Room hire per day £50<br />
Day delegate rate £35pp<br />
1/2 day rate £25 (does not include lunch)</p>
<p style="border:0;">
<strong>Includes:-</strong> tea, coffee & buscuits on arrival, mid-morning and afternoon. A one course lunch or soup & sandwiches. Jugs of iced water & squash.
</p>
```

I still see special characters in my Browser like so:

[image]

Why am i still getting these special characters ??

Comment: FYI-It is displayed correctly in my browser.

Comment: @SachDan whats ur browser ? i am on chrome  , windows8.1

Comment: How it is written in your source-code?

Comment: If you look at the source of that page in the browser, you'll see that the source contains these special characters (a question mark in a black block) They are displayed on page in the same way they're displayed in source (by Chrome). If however, one copies your html from this post and sets the content-type, the pound characters are all shown as expected. TL;DR - It appears your text-editor may be misbehaving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between 'encoding' and 'characterset'. If they do not match, the wrong characters will be displayed.

The minus signs in the lines with "Classroom style" and "U shape" are hex 0xE28093, and the currency characters are 0xC2A3. A browser might not be able to show the correct characters for these hex codes. To avoid this, you should replace the currency character with `&pound;` and the & character with `&amp;` and the minus sign with just the minus sign.

See the [HTML Codes](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm).

Answer (score 2):

As I can see, hyphen in "Boardroom set up **-** 20 delegates" is printed correctly.
But hyphen "Classroom style **–** 15 delegates" is showed as unknown.

You might have copied and pasted these contents from somewhere else.

It will work properly if you delete those special character and re-type it in your editor.

I,also had gone through the same issue and above solution worked for me.Better if you can give a try.